# Best way to display so many options in a select field within a form type using Sonata

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am using sonata as backoffice for my web application.

I have to create a question category object using stored questions in my data base.

To do this I am using a form with a select where I display all questions as options.

The challenging point that as the number of questions gets bigger the form gets much more longer, and I hate that.

[image]

I welcome any suggestion to improve the questions display.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no simple solution. Look at the tags on the StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

> The challenging point that as the number of questions gets bigger the form gets much more longer, and I hate that.

that is not really a problem, but I am going to show you a very nice alternative.

Use the **sonata_type_model** field type, which is explained pretty well in the [sonata documenatation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-model)

Please provide some code for your admin and entity class if you need more help